# Simple rotation... impossible?

Tags: transforms

I'm feeling crazy, why is it so hard to just rotate objects predictably in blender? 
No matter what setting I use, I cant get things to rotate how I want to.
Watch these two webms. Imagine the front beveled face is the face of a human and I want him to look up = rotate his head back a bit.
It would stand to reason that blender has some kind of internal object rotation right? Well that setting doesnt work either. Nothing works for me.

[image: desired rotation]

Pathetic attempts to make it work but I cant:

http://webm.land/media/reS6.webm

http://webm.land/media/9cqn.webm

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking... put try turning on the spherical rotate transform tool -- the gyroscope looking one. That allows you to rotate specifically by X Y and Z. Using the Transform Rotation sliders on the N tab will too... Rotation occurs around the object's origin, which you can position as/where you like. Some rotations, like the head rotation you mention, can be made even more natural looking with armatures.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/basics.html#rotate

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you want to rotate the object around its local axis. To do that, choose ***local*** [transformation orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html) and then access it with shortcuts by pressing **R, X, X**. The second x (or other axis) keypress switches from global to whatever transform orientation is selected from the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Leander I already did that, the second video shows axis locked rotation while local axis is selected. Still doesnt change the weird behavior. Yes, I can use the rotation gizmo just fine but this is supposed to be the faster and easier way yes? Well it doesnt work at all for me.

Comment: If you want to rotate on its own angle, do as Leander says (if it doesn't work properly, perhaps you have made a rotation of your cube in Edit mode?). If you want to rotate it around a different pivot than its center, move the 3D cursor to the point that is supposed to be the pivot, and select 3D Cursor in the Pivot Point  dropdown menu on the horizontal bar on bottom of the 3D view.

Comment: @moonboots please explain this then, I made a new cube and I definitely didnt make any edit rotation (how would I fix that then? I already tired 'set origin to geometry', didnt fix it). As you can see, the rotation gizmo works totally different from the rotation shortcut. Why?! http://webm.land/media/TCVd.webm

Comment: it looks like this time you have enabled the Local orientation on the dropdown menu of the horizontal menu bar. If you want to rotate your cube on its own axis, you can either do it with the widget, or pressing keys. In the second case, you still have to press R and twice the axis. Now, does it rotate around the axis you want? By default it will be its origin point, but you can change the rotation pivot with the Pivot Point dropdown menu of the horizontal menu bar.

Comment: ohhhhh twice the axis.... well I didnt know that, it makes no sense with what the gui is showing though. If I select local up top then I expect all rotations to start locally....and the popup actually seems to do something completely different, I havent figured that out.

Comment: The dropdown menu is just to display the 3D manipulator widget.

Comment: The solution appears to be *literally* what I wrote, please read more carefully! The *transform orientation* which is selected from the dropdown is the one which is used after pressing the axis key (X/Y/Z) the second time.

Comment: Where the object "Origin" is will make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

It looks from your video as if you are rotating on the Global (World) axes, where what you would like is a rotation of the cube about one of its own local axes. *If you haven't reoriented the cube in Edit Mode since it was created*, its local axes will still run from the cube's center through the centers of its faces.

*In that case*, as you have, you can just set the Transform Orientation (in the header at the bottom of the 3D View)  to 'Local'. Set the pvot point to the center of rotation you want ..(e.g. 'Individual Origin(s))

The primary, default, orientation for transformations is always Global. To reach the secondary orientation ( the one in the header ), you have to hit the constraint key(s) twice. So hitting <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>  will let you rotate the cube around its local axes.

(If you rotate all or part of an object's *mesh* in Edit Mode, that's all you have rotated. The object's local axes remain where they were before the edit.)

Comment: (Oops. I've just repeated Leander's comment)